# How to include a dictionary in this regex expression

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, dictionary

I'm starting with Javascript, I have created this function to validate certain words on input, (return true or false)

```
export default function validate(props) {
  return props.match(/war|gun|kill/g) != null;
}
```

But I will be including in the future more words and the regex expression will be very long, can you tell me a better way to rewrite this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a list of words, and include regex in the words, such as `guns?` for singular and plural form.

Here is a `flagString` function based on your example:

```
function flagString(str) {
    const bannedRe = new RegExp('\\b(' + banned.join('|') + ')\\b', 'i');
    return bannedRe.test(str);
}

var banned = [ 'guns?', 'kill', 'war' ];

console.log(flagString('this is ok'));        // returns false
console.log(flagString('guns are not ok'));   // returns true
console.log(flagString('to kill is not ok')); // returns true
```

Notes:

- The `'\\b('` and `')\\b'` anchor the words on boundaries, this is to avoid false positives
- The `.join('|')` joins the words into a single regex with *OR*ed words, so that you can test your string in a single swoop for performance